# How to make a View only show it results if the last of multiple exposed filters has a value selected?

Tags: views

I have a View with three exposed filters. We do not want to show any results until the user has selected a value for the last filter. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Set `Territory Coverage` as required in Exposed fitler settings.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is what I ended up doing. It removed the 'Any' option from the list and auto-selected the first option which is not what we wanted so I ended up writing an alter function to insert a '-select an option- as the default.